# Windows add to text file context menu "open in tail mode"

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

I want to add "open in tail mode" to the windows text file context menu using power shell, the power shell script is ready and working but how do I add it and link it to context menu ?

Tried several guides online with no success other tools you need to open and select the file and are abit overkill.

the PowerShell basic script to add some color to make it more readable:

```
do {
  get-content $logfile -wait -tail 1 | ForEach-Object {
    switch -Regex ($_) {
    "\[ERROR\]" { Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Red }
    "\[DEBUG\]" { Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Yellow }
    "\[INFO\]" { Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor White }
    "\[WARNING\]" { Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Blue }
    Default { Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor White }
    }
  }
} while ($false) # dummy loop so that `break` can be used.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the content bellow as a .reg file and execute it to create the context menu for log file extentions.
Put the real path of your script

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\.log]
@="Log.File"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Log.File\shell\OpenTailMode]
@="Open in Tail mode"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Log.File\shell\OpenTailMode\command]
@="PowerShell -File \"C:\\temp\\MyScript.ps1\" %1"
```

The %1 will be the log file right clicked that will be passed as argument to your PowerShell Script, so add this line at the beginning of your script:

```
$logfile = $Args[0]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the replay, I executed the .reg file after editing the changes but I still cant see it in context menu.
what do I need to do to bind it to txt file instead of log file ?

Comment: Do you have the context menu "Open in Tail mode" for a .log file ?

Comment: No, even did a restart just to be sure no error executing the reg file.

Comment: It works for me with .log files, I have the context menu "Open in Tail mode". Navigate to the registry and check if the mentioned keys/values exist.

Comment: Its working on my home laptop but not on my work laptop so it most be some policy blocking me, but it works ! so thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Via Powershell:

```
#Create a SendTo menu shortcut to call program.

  $SendToPath = "$DestinationPath\AppData\Roaming\" +
                "Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\"
  If (!(Test-path -Path "$SendToPath$PgmBase.lnk")) {
    
    $WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
    $Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut(
                "$SendToPath\$PgmBase.lnk")
    $Shortcut.TargetPath   = 
     "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"   
    $Shortcut.Arguments    = "-File `"$PSScriptRoot\$PgmName`""
    $Shortcut.WindowStyle  = 4 #0=Max 4=Normal 7=Minimized
    $Shortcut.IconLocation = 
     "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
    $Shortcut.Save()
  
    $("The $PgmBase option has been added to" +
            "File Explorer SendTo menu.")
             
  } #End If (!(Test-Path...

  Else {
     $("The $PgmBase.lnk shortcut already exists " +
                "in the File Explorer SendTo menu.")
  }
```

You can include the above code in a Function wrapper then add a Parameter to your main program to accept a [Switch]parameter like -Install or -Setup and test for it then call the function if the switch is present.

HTH